# show images to related sku

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, products

I am using magento v1.9.2 facing a issue, and also looking for idea how to achieve this.

I have product which say 'shirt' in 4 colors and each color have some variation images. I sucessfully done the configure products but facing two issues.

### [image]

> 1. When I select the color let suppose green and then I select size, the big/main image change to default image(i.e black), but if I select
>      size first and then color, then the main images show the selected
>      one(i.e Green)
> 2. after click buy now, the cart shows black color instead of which I selected.   but its shows selected sku in order tab in admin section.

Also I am looking for some reference, if I have some variation of each product like say green. then how can I show the images only related to green.
[image]

Should I create group product?

Any suggestions always welcome..

Comment: Can you detail how you've created your configurable products? You should have 1 configurable product with both size and color as options. Then create as much simple product combinations as you have to, S green, M green... L back, XL black ... and then assign them to your configurable product (from inside the configurable product admin page).

Comment: yes @JulienLachal, exactly did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your second query.

"after click buy now, the cart shows black color instead of which I selected. but its shows selected sku in order tab in admin section."

Go to Admin panel System >> Configuration >> Sales >> Checkout >>Shopping Cart

change "Configurable Product Image" Option  and select "Product Thumbnail Itself" and save.

Comment: I try this, but still its showing same default image, do we have other setting ????